# I need to calculate the number of characters comprised between multiple occurrences of two characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to calculate the length of the text between <> in a long input string, where the <> will mostly be repeated multiple times by a user.

```
   var Msg1 = "The lengh of <this> has to be calculated. And also <of this>. And of <this>";
   var regex = /<([^>]*)>/g;
   var IntExam = regex.exec(Msg1);
   var IntExL = IntExam[1].length;
   alert(IntExL);
```

But I only get the wrong length, when I'd like to get the lenght of all the text comprised by <>.

Comment: You need to understand how `.exec` works :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a loop:

```
var Msg1 = "The lengh of <this> has to be calculated. And also <of this>. And of <this>";
var regex = /<([^>]*)>/g;
var totalLength = 0;
do {
  var IntExam = regex.exec(Msg1);
  if(!IntExam) break;
  var IntExL = IntExam[1].length;
  totalLength += IntExL;
} while (IntExam);
alert(totalLength);
```

---

Or a concise version (derived from JaromandaX's comment):

```
var Msg1 = "The lengh of <this> has to be calculated. And also <of this>. And of <this>";
var regex = /<([^>]*)>/g;
var totalLength = Msg1.match(regex).map(v => v.length-2).reduce((a, b) => a + b);
alert(totalLength);
```

Comment: or ... `var totalLength = Msg1.match(regex).map(v => v.length).reduce((a, b) => a + b)`

Comment: so: `Msg1.match(regex).map(v => v.length - 2).reduce((a, b) => a + b) ` - because the `<>` are matched - which you've done :p

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers, now it works properly :)